# Docker Instalation Kiwi Tcms with Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, kiwi-tcms

I started Kiwi TCMS in Docker (k8s) with Postgresql. It started ok, but when I wanted to run migrations it crashed. I used [this docker-compose](https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/blob/master/docker-compose.postgres) for inspiration.
Log shows problem with connection with MySQL. But I changed configuration for engine. See:

```
bash-4.2$ KIWI_DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 59, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

Any ideas where can be problem please?

Comment: It would be better if you just create an answer if you have a solution, instead of updating the question.

Comment: I second kutschkem' comment: please create an answer.

Comment: thanks guy. I lost my manieres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem was with version of used docker image. 
I used docker image tag `kiwitcms/kiwi:6.2` and I thought it's the latest release. But it's not. This version(docker image) doesn't have code for changing DB engine. I changed version of docker tag to `latest` and it works pretty well now.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash-4.2$ KIWI_DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
```

This is setting an environment variable inside the docker container and I'm not sure if that works or which one takes precendece.

If you want somebody to help you post the entire docker-compose.yml (or whatever kubernetes control file you use). Clearly the application thinks it is configured to talk to MySQL and fails when MySQL isn't available.